# Visual studio installer project - build platform configuration is N/A .. how to change?

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild

I m using VSTS build task for building msi files from installer projects.
I get below log message and no msi file is generated(project is being skipped always from build) . I don't see platform option dropdown to select "Any CPU " from build configuration manager.

Please help. Click on the below links to see screen shot of build configuration and build task

[build configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SNPh.png)

[Build tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMZYC.png)

**------ Skipped Build: Project: Setup4, Configuration: Release ------
Project not selected to build for this solution configuration**

However msi file is generating fine when I do manual build on setup project. Not sure why platform option is missing for setup project..?????

Comment: Is your issue solved and is there any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

From the build log, TFS is using Release Configuration. And from the log, it seems that your project doesn't select build configuration for Release configuration.

So, in the configuration manager of Visual Studio, select build for release configuration. Then check in to TFS.
[image]

You should pay attention that, both project and solution has configuration settings. If you want to build solution in TFS, change the solution settings. If you want to build project in TFS, change the project configuration settings.